# como fazer a chamada system retornar a string invertida?

Tags: python

```
print('Listening on {} {}'.format(ip,porta))
     (obj, cliente) = server.accept()
     print('connect received from {}'.format(cliente[0]))
    while (True):
        msg = obj.recv(1024)
        **system('rev')**
        server.close()
```

Comment: O que exatamente o programa deveria fazer? O que está fazendo atualmente?

Comment: bem, eu devo montar um servidor que faça uma chamada do comando rev do linux e o retorne ao usuário.

Comment: Por que não `print(msg[::-1])`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: então, eu gostaria que o utilitário do linux fizesse este trabalho para mim, sem utilizar os recursos da linguagem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: import socket
    from os import system
    ip = '0.0.0.0'
    porta = 663
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((ip, porta))
    server.listen(5)
    print('Listening on {} {}'.format(ip, porta))
    (obj, cliente) = server.accept()
    print('connect received from {}'.format(cliente[0]))

    while (True):
        msg = obj.recv(1024)
        msg = msg[:-1]
        system('rev')
        server.close()
    except:
    print('error')
    server.close()

Comment: não gostaria de usar recursos da linguagem e sim o utilitário rev do linux, então eu gostaria de fazer uma chamada de sistema e ele faça esse trabalho para mim, obrigado pela ajuda e desculpe algum erro, minha primeira vez aqui!

Comment: Uma dica: em vez de colocar código (e qualquer outra informação adicional) nos comentários, é melhor [edit] a sua pergunta e colocar tudo lá. Além de concentrar toda a informação relevante em um lugar só, na pergunta é possível [formatar o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) e deixá-lo mais legível do que nos comentários. Editar posts é uma prática comum no site, sugiro que leia a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) também para mais informações sobre o [funcionamento do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o comando `rev` com `|` do bash:

`echo 12345|rev`

Retorna:

`54321`

Ou seja: `**system('{comando que retorna string}|rev')**`

Comment: então, acrescentei o echo , system('{echo}|rev'), como passar a variável com o texto como parâmetro para a chamada de sistema? essa e minha maior duvida, porque quando conecto no servidor e chamo o rev ele fica ativo no servidor!, dai tenho que ir la e digitar a mensagem, gostaria de receber do usuário e passar a variável como parâmetro para a chamada de sistema!

Comment: Então, o {} é só um exemplo, mas você também pode fazer: `**system('programa {}|rev'.format(texto_como_param))**`